# Mandrill "Send A Copy Of Every Email To This Address" : CC or BCC?

Tags: mandrill

On the 'Sending Defaults' settings page of [mandrill](https://mandrillapp.com/settings/sending-options), there is a setting 'Send A Copy Of Every Email To This Address' field.

I would like to know 2 things: Is this sent using 'to', 'CC' or 'BCC', and if I send to X users, do I receive X emails or just 1?

I assume 'BCC' and '1' are the answers, but mandrill's test suite doesnt actually send emails, so this function isn't triggered and I cannot find any documentation on this.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to your question ?

Comment: I did not. I stopped using mandrill over their lack of documentation.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me ! Out of curiosity, what service did you migrate to ? I'm also planning on migrating to something else.

Comment: I think the company decided to just use mailchimp and write a custom component for handling transactional emails.